# Scrapy error signals - not giving any info when timeouting (or other NW issue) while scraping

Tags: scrapy

I'm doing some scraping (Scrapy 1.3.3) , and verifying if scrapes are successful/unsuccessful - using the Scrapy signals for `spider_opened` and `spider_closed`.

**Part of extensions.py code for `spider_closed`**

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class SendEmail(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.fromaddr = FROMADDR
    self.toaddr  = TOADDR

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    # first check if the extension should be enabled and raise
    # NotConfigured otherwise
    if not crawler.settings.getbool('MYEXT_ENABLED'):
        raise NotConfigured

    # instantiate the extension object
    ext = cls()
crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)

def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
    logger.info("closed spider %s", spider.name)
    pipelines.active_scrape.scrape_end = datetime.datetime.now()
    if reason == "finished":
        pipelines.active_scrape.scrape_status = "Finished"
        pipelines.active_scrape.scrape_status_reason = reason
    elif reason == "cancelled":
        pipelines.active_scrape.scrape_status = "Failed"
        pipelines.active_scrape.scrape_status_reason = reason
    elif reason == "shutdown":
        pipelines.active_scrape.scrape_status = "Failed"
        pipelines.active_scrape.scrape_status_reason = reason
```

**Settings.py - uncommented text only**

```
BOT_NAME = 'testna'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['testna.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'testna.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'testna.pipelines.TestnaPipeline': 300,
}

MYEXT_ENABLED = True
EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
    'testna.extensions.SendEmail':500
}
```

**Spider - removed actual data and replaced with xyz**

```
import scrapy
import re
from decimal import Decimal

class TestnaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "testna"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
        'http://www.xyz.example',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        xs = response.css("#xyz")
        for x in xs:
            URL = 'http://www.xyz.example'
            ID = x.css("xyz")
            ID2 = x.css("xyz")

            for ID, naziv in zip(ID, ID2):
                yield scrapy.Request(url=URL+ID, callback=lambda request,naziv=naziv: self.parse_x(naziv,request))

    def parse_x(self, id_x, response):

        xs = response.css("xyz") 
        for x in xs:

            desc1 = ''.join(x.css(".xyz::text").extract()) 
            desc2 = ''.join(x.css("xyz::text").extract())

            yield {"description1": desc1, "description2": descr2, "ID": id_x}

        NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = ".Pagination-item--next a::attr(href)"
        next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                response.urljoin(next_page),
                callback=lambda request,id_x=id_x: self.parse_x(id_x,request)
            )
```

When a potential network issue happens and Scrapy isn't able to fetch network data (No route to host, DNS lookup failed - some of which I have encountered), which leads to retries and closing the spider, Scrapy signals that the spider finishes, without any issue description.

**Log:**

```
2017-08-01 14:47:31 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.xyz.example> (failed 1 times): An error occurred while connecting: 113: No route to host.
2017-08-01 14:47:31 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.xyz.example> (failed 2 times): An error occurred while connecting: 113: No route to host.
2017-08-01 14:47:37 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.xyz.example> (failed 3 times): An error occurred while connecting: 113: No route to host.
2017-08-01 14:47:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.xyz.example>: An error occurred while connecting: 113: No route to host.
2017-08-01 14:47:56 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 4 pages (at 4 pages/min), scraped 49 items (at 49 items/min)
2017-08-01 14:48:56 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 4 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 49 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 14:49:56 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 4 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 49 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 14:50:21 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.xyz.example> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting http://www.xyz.example took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2017-08-01 14:50:22 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.xyz.example> (failed 2 times): An error occurred while connecting: 113: No route to host.
2017-08-01 14:50:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.xyz.example> (failed 3 times): An error occurred while connecting: 113: No route to host.
2017-08-01 14:50:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.xyz.example>: An error occurred while connecting: 113: No route to host.
2017-08-01 14:50:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-08-01 14:50:29 [testna.extensions] INFO: closed spider testna
```

How can I verify that the whole scrape went fine without NW issues which led to closing the spider like above?

I tried all of the current signals, but none of them has any relevance to potential NW issues.

Comment: ...  In the future,  you will soon learn that when issuing a request for help/troubleshoot it is absolutely important to provide  any source code or at the very least a error log,  picture,  diagram whatever of what exactly it is that you're talking about. We can't help you if we don't know what the problem is!  If you update your question  appropriately I will gladly help you out

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks, I tried to enrich the question and be more specific.

Comment: Hey @HrvojeBilić !  I was going to answer official... I Kinda went over board... lol but essentially im just wrote on THE POSSIBLE reasons why, Having a full snippet of your projects is neccesary because I wrote a lot of "IF this the THAT"... Be sure to leave out any sensitive info if thats the problem?  But need to take a look at your settings py, and the spider... ALSO need to know if your running locally or on a server maybe? FIY the relvance trace back for "NW" issue IS the 113... means NO response...  ALSO when you say "When a potential network issue " .. [CONTINUE]

Comment: Could I assume that you mean that the spider does work properly but at some point chokes out? or has there been no instace ever reaching the site ...

Comment: Hi! Sure, shouldn't be a problem to also include the settings and spider info. Will add them to the initial thread. I'm running the spider locally on a virtual machine (Ubuntu).
The spider works perfectly, but I wanted to "simulate" possible problems to see how Scrapy will react on it - on occasion I disconnected the network adapter while scraping (no route to host) or using unsupported network type (DNS lookup failed). So basically I wanted to verify if something happens during scraping that the log shows unsuccessful scrape (not fully executed).

Answer (score 0):

Let's go ahead and both agree that the "113" is in theory not a response. After all, it's not from the server/website the initial request is sent, so using the native signaling won't do it since we just agreed its not really a response.

```
An error occurred while connecting: 113: No route to host.
```

This could could arise from a good amount of reasons, point is: once twisted tries resolving, its like it physical "reach" or can "touch it". I'll stick to the question but if you have couple minutes to spare, [read this](http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/icmp_int.htm). It is good to know this stuff but you can just skip straight to any  DHCP and ARP layering mentions.

### The network

How to debug this thing? I commend you for going out of your way and creating a custom logger extension! But your only going to get you the same info (assuming you have also enabled "Depth" middleware, and log level critical, but yes, not much). I'd start by looking from inside out.

So you want to simulate this event as it where to happen in a everyday scenario: log it, and stdout it verbosely in a text file? straight to terminal? both? There's an extension for that!

[image]

Stacktracedump might be what you're looking for, whether you're logging to a file or to output. In theory you can create a signal for when that "113" error shows up, which the could trigger a function of your own design.

You asked:

> How can I verify that the whole scrape went fine without NW issues which led to closing the spider like above?

Well, aside from the obvious stack trace  right before MAX TIME wait before chokes out, I can think of some cool stuff to do with that "custom signaling" from the stdout of the spider instance.

Since you're using telnet already, how about pausing the spider, to then send out request to check on HTTP status - hits 200! unpause and/or push some sort of notification.

Wait! the error came about due to local network issue, and we can't send emails? Well, you could however use your LAN to push some sort of notification, through an email server or sockets

I know that's a lot of customization and additional development but as to your question, verify if scrape went with out a hitch! watching for 133... stacktracedump, though not a signal you can create a trigger function if it were to show up. If it doesn't show up, I guess it was a successful scrape!